# How to make simple "FOR" based formula in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a simple (I believe it's simple) formula to use in my google spreadsheets (so it must be in GAS)
I have 2 columns - first is filled with NAMES and the other with NUMBERS.
I need function to fill another column with NAMES as many times as their corresponding NUMBER.

So I have something like:

- Peter 2
- Mark 1
- Alexander 3

Function needs to fill a column like that:

- Peter
- Peter
- Mark
- Alexander
- Alexander
- Alexander

I tried doing it with just formulas but coudnt do it. I am totally new to GAS so I also coudn't make this myself based on similar things i found on stackoverflow.

Comment: Excel vba and google app script are two different languages.  their syntax will not work one with the other.  Which do you want?

Comment: Excel has a [REPT](http://www.bing.com/search?q=excel+rept+function&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE10SR). Perhaps google spreadsheets has a similar one ... Yup ... [it does](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en), exact syntax actually. You can combine this function with a Text-to-Columns and Transpose to get what you need.

Comment: @ScottCraner - i need google app script.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I do need to repeat words from column 1 but I need them in seperate cells, one under another in the same column. Is this result possible to get through this syntax?

Comment: @saint337 - yes, use REPT function with comma separation. Then do `Text-to-Columns`, then do `Transpose`. If you have a high volume of rows this may be a bit laborious.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman well, yes, there is big number of it, changing everyday. I need make it automatic so I guess creating simple function with "for" loop would be best. I just dont know how to make it in GAS

Comment: @saint337 - looks like it times to learn to write google apps scripts :)

Comment: It's not clear if you are looking for formula or a script. In any case, you didn't show what did you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

[Working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HU2dJ6L_9RU3ofyS2p-9NWRDMcZ1PvSwotJX0InE8U0/edit?usp=sharing)

The formula is `split(join("",arrayformula(rept(A2:A5&",",B2:B5))),",")`

Where

- `rept(A2:A5&",",B2:B5)` append "," to A values and then repeat by B times
- `arrayformula(rept(...))` iterate the formula through all values
- `join("",arrayformula)` joins the list with empty ("") separator
- and `split(join(...)))` break up the list into an array

Comment: Good idea: you may also transpose. `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("",REPT(A2:A5&",",B2:B5))),","))`. @saint337, this answer fits you?

Answer (score 0):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, try:

```
Sub Relist()
   Dim N As Long, K As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, ii As Long

   K = 1
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = 1 To N
      v = Cells(i, 1).Value
      j = Cells(i, 2).Value
      For ii = 1 To j
         Cells(K, 3).Value = v
         K = K + 1
      Next ii
   Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It doesnt compile so I guess it's made for VBA. I need to use it in google spreadsheats so it must be GAS

Comment: @saint337  This is ***VBA***  the logic is EXTREMELY simple.....just translate the VBA to your language of choice.